# Webpack - mimics synchronous lazy import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, preact

For code splitting purpose, I have my "posts" data in json format separated by file ie. `sample-post-1.json`. I then have my `<Post>` component targetted to import those posts dynamically (but the import must be sync for prerendering to work), smthing like:

```
// router
<Post path="/post/:slug" />

// Post
class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // try to dynamically lazy import, use import() to hint webpack we want to 
    // code split this module. but the "real" import needed to be sync
    import(`@/data/posts/${this.props.matches.slug}`)
    // require(...) doesnt work and throw error, no idea why. hence below
    const post = __webpack_require__(
      require.resolveWeak(`@/data/posts/${this.props.matches.slug}`)
    )

    this.state = { post }
  }

  render() {...}
}
```

Above works but it feels too hacky, are there alternative ways of achieving the same result without either `__webpack_require__`/`require.resolveWeak`?

Comment: why not sync load, since you need it to be preload anyways? It is too much of a hasle for the same amount of work.

Comment: if I have 1000 posts the whole of them will be in the same chunk when sync loading. Each post page should only load its own chunk

Answer (score 2):

The solution in your question is the only way I'm aware of currently.

However, the `require` variable in your code is not present in all circumstances (eg. libraries with ES6 modules), so here is a version that works more generically (using only the `__webpack_require__` variable):

```
declare var __webpack_require__;
function WP_ImportSync(name_ending: string) {
    // Try to dynamically lazy import. Use import() to hint webpack we want to code split this module, but the "real" import needs to be synchronous.
    import(name_ending);
    
    //return __webpack_require__(require.resolve(name));
    const moduleID = Object.keys(__webpack_require__.m).find(a=>a.endsWith(name_ending));
    return __webpack_require__(moduleID);
}
```

Like you said, it ain't pretty, but it can get the job done. (so long as you know the parent project is using webpack, of course, as the standardized `import(...)` function has no synchronous version that I'm aware of)